# Directional derivative of function at specific point

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

If I've a function (in this case also differentiable):

```
x^3/3 - x*y^2 - x/8 + y^2
```

how can I find quickly the directional derivative of the function in (1,1) with respect to the unit vector v(sqrt(3)/2, 1/2).
Finding the gradient, and run the dot product.
But what if the function had not been differentiable?

Comment: Here is an example of such sort:  `{D[Sqrt[RealAbs[x^2 - x*y]], x], 
  D[Sqrt[RealAbs[x^2 - x*y]], y]} /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}` produces `{Indeterminate, Indeterminate}` and `D[Sqrt[RealAbs[x^2 - x*y]] /. {x -> t, y -> sqrt[2]*t}, t] /. t -> 0` performs `Indeterminate` too.

Comment: There's a ResourceFunction: [`DirectionalD`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DirectionalD)

Comment: @user64494, sorry but I do not understand... how can use this instruction to find the directional derivate?

Comment: Try it:`(Grad[x^3/3 - x*y^2 - x/8 + y^2, {x, y}] /. {x -> 1, 
    y -> 1}).Normalize[{Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example, where a function of two variables

```
f[x_,y_]:=Sqrt[RealAbs[x^2 - x*y]]
```

is not differentiable at the origin, but its directional derivative at the origin for many directions exists.

We consider the restriction of the function `f[x,y]` on the ray from the origin along a vector `{a,b}`, preserving the scale by

```
g[t] := f[x, y] /. {x -> a/Norm[{a, b}]*t, y -> b/Norm[{a, b}]*t}
```

assuming `t>=0`. Now

```
D[g[t],t]
(*(((2 a^2 t)/(Abs[a]^2 + Abs[b]^2) - (2 a b t)/(   Abs[a]^2 + Abs[b]^2)) ((a^2 t^2)/
(Abs[a]^2 + Abs[b]^2) - (a b t^2)/(Abs[a]^2 + Abs[b]^2)))/(2 RealAbs[(a^2 t^2)/
( Abs[a]^2 + Abs[b]^2) - (a b t^2)/(Abs[a]^2 + Abs[b]^2)]^(3/2))*)
```

and

```
Limit[%, t -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"] // Simplify
```

$$ 
\begin{cases}
 \sqrt{-\frac{a (a-b)}{a^2+b^2}} & a\neq 0\land a^2<a b
   \\
 \sqrt{\frac{a (a-b)}{a^2+b^2}} & (b=0\land a\neq
   0)\lor (b<0\land (a\geq 0\lor a\leq b))\lor
   (b>0\land (a\geq b\lor a\leq 0)) \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{cases}
$$
It should be noticed that

```
ResourceFunction["DirectionalD"][Sqrt[RealAbs[x^2 - x*y]], {a, b}, {x, y}]
(*-((b x (x^2 - x y))/(2 RealAbs[x^2 - x y]^(3/2))) +(a (2 x - y) (x^2 - x y))/(2 RealAbs[x^2 - x y]^(3/2))*)
```

, but

```
Limit[%, {x, y} -> {0, 0}]
(*Indeterminate*)
```

Comment: The command `Limit[ResourceFunction["DirectionalD"][Sqrt[RealAbs[x^2 - x*y]], 
   Normalize[{a, b}], {x, y}] /. y -> b/a*x, x -> 0, 
 Direction -> "FromAbove"]` results in $$\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\sqrt{-\frac{a}{a-b}} (b-a)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} & (a>0\land a<b\land b>0)\lor (a<0\land a>b\land b<0) \\
 \frac{a \sqrt{1-\frac{b}{a}}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} & (b\leq 0\land a>0)\lor (b\geq 0\land a<0)\lor (b>0\land a\geq b)\lor (b<0\land a\leq b) \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array} $$

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of the directional derivative:
Let f,z,v be vectors and t a scalar, the directional derivative of f[z] along v is

```
Limit[(f[z + t v]-f[z])/t,t->0]
```

For the above example with f[x,y]=Sqrt[RealsAbs[x^2-x y]]

```
Limit[((f[x, y] /. {Thread[{x, y} -> {x, y} + t {1, 1/2}]}) - 
    f[x, y])/t, t -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
```

Comment: Unfortunately. `Limit[((f[x, y] /. {Thread[{x, y} -> {x, y} + t {1, 1/2}]}) - 
     f[x, y])/t, t -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"] /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}` performs `Indeterminate`. Also up to the common definition, the vector `{1, 1/2}` should be normalized.

Comment: Compare the results of `f[x_, y_] := 
 x*y; Limit[((f[x, y] /. {Thread[{x, y} -> {x, y} + t {1, 1/2}]}) - 
    f[x, y])/t, t -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]` which performs `{1/2 (x + 2 y)}` and `Limit[((f[x, y] /. {Thread[{x, y} -> {x, y} + t {2, 1}]}) - f[x, y])/
  t, t -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]` which results in `{x + 2 y}` though the directions are identical.

Comment: If you interpret the directional derivative as velocity of change of f[] if you pass {x,y} with the velocity v, then it is clear that the larger Abs[v], the larger the derivative.

Comment: Is this your personal point of view? Can you give an available reference to that interpretation? Wiki (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) says nothing about such interpretation.

Comment: There are two different notions: the directional derivative and the derivative along a vector.

Comment: The second is a generalization of the first. If the vector in question is a unit vector, both definitions are the same.